# Window resize issue in jQuery Popup

Tags: jquery, popup

I started writing a very Simple jQuery Popup myself.

Here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pop").click(function(){
         openPopup();
    });
    $("#close").click(function(){
        closePopup();
    });
  });

function openPopup(){
$("#overlay_form").css({
    left: ($(window).width() - $('#overlay_form').width()) / 2,
    top: ($(window).width() - $('#overlay_form').width()) / 7,
    position:'absolute'
});

$("#overlay_form").fadeIn(1000);

   }
 function closePopup(){
$("#overlay_form").fadeOut(500);
}

$(window).bind('resize',openPopup);

</script>
```

Everything is working fine. But the problem is here in this code

```
   $(window).bind('resize',openPopup);
```

This code is to keep the popup in the center of the browser. But, even after i close the popup, if i resize the browser this code again opens up the popup.

I need to use a if condition somewhere in the code!. Where to use and how to use?. 
Give me a solution please!.

Comment: I think you should not resize popup window when window is resized. That's overkill and users don't expect pop up window changes its size when they resize or maximize window.

Comment: @bighostkim Actually i'm not resizing the popup window. I'm just keeping the popup at the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.fadeIn()` from the function and place it in the click handler.

```
$("#pop").click(function(){
  $("#overlay_form").fadeIn(1000);
  resizePop();
});


function resizePop(){
  if(!$("#overlay_form").is(':visible')){
    return;
  } 
  $("#overlay_form").css({
      left: ($(window).width() - $('#overlay_form').width()) / 2,
      top: ($(window).width() - $('#overlay_form').width()) / 7,
      position:'absolute'
  });
}

$(window).bind('resize',resizePop);
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution that you are looking for is really quite simple--when you find it . . .

Within your document ready function add a function that fires during a browser resize event; within that function re-center your dialog:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('#overlay_form').dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
    });

});
```

By the way, when you are opening your dialog there is no need to specify top or left, as the default position is center.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `bind` is deprecated, use `.on()` from jQuery 1.7 and next, your event handling **fails** when the popup boxes is faded out, so limiting the resize then event handler to one function causes the script to break.

```
$(window).on('resize',function() {
   openPopup();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $("#overlay_form").is(':visible') ) {
    // it's showing, so recenter it
}
else {
    // it's hidden, so you don't care
}
```

I recommend that you separate the re-centering code from the opening code so you can call them more specifically based on the circumstances.